# How to set "keep with next" paragraph option in Google AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am using Google App Script to programmatically create a document.
I cannot find a way to set "keep with next" via App Script.
Using the UI, this setting is present under *Format > Line Spacing > Keep with next*,
but I cannot find a *Paragraph* method to mimic it via code.

Here my code. Data contains an array of objects that needs to be rendered as a nested list.

```js
data.items.forEach(({ item, options }) => {
    let elements = [];
    let itemTextClone = tpl.getListItems()[0].copy();
    itemTextClone.setText(item);
    elements.push(body.appendListItem(itemTextClone).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER));
    options.forEach((option) => {
        let itemOptClone = tpl.getListItems()[1].copy()
        itemOptClone.setText(option);
        elements.push(body.appendListItem(itemOptClone).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.LATIN_LOWER));
    });
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO APPLY "KEEP WITH NEXT" to all elements except the last one
    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    elements.slice(0,-1).foreach((element) => ?????? )
});
```

Comment: Seems that this feature has not be implemented into Apps Script ? Docs API (yet). You can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you [enable the Advanced Docs service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

The [ParagraphStyle](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#ParagraphStyle) object allows the field `keepWithNext`.

To make an [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#UpdateParagraphStyleRequest), you'll need to know the `startIndex` and `endIndex` of the paragraph in question. You can get that from a call to `Docs.Document.get(YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID)`. The returned `.body.content` field is an array of elements, each with a `startIndex` and `endIndex`.  This function updates one paragraph:

```
function setKeepWithNext(docId, elementIndex)
{
  var doc = Docs.Documents.get(docId)
  var paragraph = doc.body.content[elementIndex]
  // You can construct an array of these requests and pass them all at once to batchUpdate:
  var request = {
    "updateParagraphStyle": {
      "paragraphStyle": {
        "keepWithNext": true,
      },
      "fields": "keepWithNext",
      "range": {
        // "segmentId": "", // An empty segment ID signifies the document's body.
        "startIndex": paragraph.startIndex,
        "endIndex": paragraph.endIndex
      }
    }
  }
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ 'requests': [request] }, docId)
}
```

You may have to inspect the results of `Docs.Document.get()` to determine the range of `elementIndex` values to use for your specific paragraphs.  One feels these indices ought to correspond to the index returned by [`body.getChildIndex(element)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildindexchild), but from inspection that doesn't seem to be the case.